# am I wrong in thinking that an author raising "no longer needed" flag is always honored?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

I believe there was a moderator post a while ago (on this meta site) which said that if an answer author raises "no longer needed" flag, the comments always get deleted.  It makes sense since comments are supposed to be information for the authors and if they read them and don't find them useful, the comments should not be sticking around to provoke discussions.

Am I wrong in thinking that this is the site's policy?

Comment: I hope that isn't the case as that would mean the author could delete any comment that is criticizing, pointing out issues/flaws, or in general that they doing like. The comments are not just there for the authors use and they can be useful for other things. And example would be on a question putting a comment in to explain a downvote which would help others as they look at the question in the review queue.

Comment: I assume this is in response to my comments on your answer which are saying that your claims that England isn't a country is incorrect? https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76687/20715

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Since the question was

> **Am I wrong in thinking that this is the site's policy?**

And the only moderator who answered it so far said that they personally did not follow such a practice, I asked if the other moderators could confirm that this was the site's policy or if it was that moderators personal methodology with regard to moderation.

I did it by raising a moderator flag on this meta question with the following note:

> One moderator has already expressed their view on this moderation issue. Can some (or all moderators), please, respond and explain if this is a site policy or if the response from the one moderator is their personal methodology? – wrod yesterday   declined - **(the other moderator)'s answer reflects moderation policy**

The actual answer mentioned the moderator's name, but I've edited it out to avoid naming the moderator (who is also a user).

This answers the question.

Comment: I tend to delete whole comment chains when I think it's not worth preserving. If I think it is worth preserving but I think it devolved into too much discussion then I move it to chat (though that's only possible once per comment chain).

Answer (score 8):

Some people tend to raise "no longer needed" flags on comments which point out flaws in their answers which they don't agree with. When I believe that the criticism is valid and useful for the readers, then I reject a "no longer needed" flag from the answer author. It's not our job to silence your critics.

I usually do delete comments flagged as "no longer needed" by the question author when the author edited their answer to fix whatever problem was pointed out.

Comment: Criticism is not an appropriate use of comments, is it?  If a different user has suggestions on how an answer should be edited, they should edit the answer and risk having their contribution undone through a rollback.  Comments should not be used as a form of additional content to an answer.  Otherwise, this encourages adding content in comments in order to avoid exposure to downvotes.  If they want to provide an alternative answer, they should write their own.

Comment: Once an author is aware of a suggestion and rejects it, and an alternative view is presented in a different answer, the only point of a comment is to antagonize the author.  Your moderation methodology may have thus contributed to increased levels of hostility on the site.  Please, reconsider.

Comment: @wrod Pointing out that an answer contains inaccurate information **is** an appropriate use of comments. The comment should stay until the inaccuracy was corrected by an edit. Especially when the answer author is uncooperative when it comes to improving their answer.

Comment: In my view, this is a significant (maybe even fundamental) change of the goal of the comments from being "suggestions on how the answers can be improved." In the cases when there is a disagreement about the validity of the content, it is an **open invitation** to flame wars.  If the range of the use of comments has always included open-ended criticism of content, please, point me to a site rule which allows this.

Comment: @wrod A user trying to hide the fact that there are issues, perceived or real, isn't going to serve the site. And if people are upvoting that comment it is likely the comment, or one similar, would get added to the post again. It doesn't do any good to have people keep adding a comment with issues of the posts and to keep removing them because the author doesn't agree with it.

Comment: @JoeW comments should not be used to add content to the site in a way which evades downvote moderation efforts.  Upvotes based on the quality of content in the comments is meaningless because comments cannot be downvoted, but it still happens because users sometimes treat comments as content instead of what they are meant to be (editorial remarks).

Comment: @wrod You just called a comment an editorial remark which would suggest that they should not be deleted if the post author doesn't agree with them.

Comment: @JoeW once the user has been made aware of the remark, it serves no further purpose.  It should not be used to evade moderation of its content through downvotes.  If you have a different answer in mind and your suggestions have been rejected, the appropriate thing to do is to write your own answer *and to delete your comment*.  Anything else is nothing but an attempt to engage in a discussion in comments.

Comment: @wrod The author of the post is not the only person that comments are directed at and it can be useful for others who are trying to properly judge a question or answer.

Comment: @JoeW whether or not that assertion is the site's policy is the very thing this meta question is trying to ascertain.

Comment: @wrod There seems to be a clear answer from a site moderator that you seem to be objecting to.

Comment: @JoeW We site moderators enforce the site policy, but we aren't the ones making it. We serve the community (and our corporate overlords). When a lot of users would want us to handle things differently (and that course of action doesn't go against Stack Exchange policy), we would change our course of action. But looking at the votes on this answer (+6/-0) this seems to be the consensus of the community.

Comment: @Philipp I understand that you enforce policy but don't make it. I was more referring the the multiple responses to the answer that kept trying to explain why it was wrong. And by Wrod's logic you could flag all of them as "no longer needed" and delete them depriving him any ability to put feedback on your answer or others to see that feedback.

Comment: @Philipp and any number of the members of the community would rather see it turn into a forum.  And that's precisely what your formula guarantees.  It's already way too chatty.  But you are now encouraging evading moderation through comments.  Comments don't get any downvotes.  So you are discouraging answers in favor of comments.  A comment with 10 upvotes may be attracting the upvotes because high numbers attract attention.  But as an answer the same content could have attracted 15 downvotes.  So bad content looks good.  AND YOU ARE ENCOURAGING THIS.

Comment: @wrod It is better to have the same comments repeated over and over again as they get deleted instead of just getting an upvote to show agreement? If you disagree with this answer you should post one of your own instead of posting multiple comments of the type that you are complaining about. You appear to be making this into a discussion about the answer.

Comment: @JoeW what are you kidding?  You repeat comments even after they haven't been deleted.  I can read off half a dozen comments (not yours) which don't even have anything to do with the posts which don't get erased even after the the flags get raised on them.

Comment: @wrod Make an answer about it instead of turning the comment thread into what you are complaining about. Let the userbase actually vote on your answer as no one is able to vote on your comments as you have pointed out.

Comment: @JoeW this is meta.  on meta there is no difference.  moderation is irrelevant here.  or at least, that's what people have kept saying for the longest time.  now that have abandoned all the rules, maybe that's not the case either.

Comment: @JoeW and if moderation does matter, why should I unilaterally disarm by exposing myself to moderation while arguing with the people won't do the same?

Comment: @wrod You should at least still provide an answer of what you think should be happening instead of ranting about the given answers.

Comment: You are going in circles, wrod and JoeW, When you don't have anything new to say, please don't comment. Repeating the same arguments over and over again does not make them any stronger.

Comment: @Philipp I would call on you to be more careful than simply relying on votes when evaluating the communities sentiment on an *issue*.  Your answer got +7/-0.  Mine got +0/-5.  But mine, not only agrees with yours, it also shows the facts which indicate that this is indeed the site's policy (rather than just a methodology of 1 moderator).  Since the 2 answers are in agreement, the sentiment expressed by the votes cannot be just about the fact matter discussed.  Otherwise, the -5 on my answer would have to indicate that the community is against this being a policy, but *for* you doing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From a non moderator point of view I feel that no one person (non moderator) should have a final say on a comment being needed or not needed on a question or answer. That would to easily allow for a user to hide negative feedback on a post that could make it harder for others to properly judge the post and quality of that post

As an example if the person feels that the post has inaccurate/false information and leave information showing why they feel that the poster should not be able to have it deleted and hide that information.

I feel it is better for the moderators to review each of those flags and handle them on a case by case basis to ensure that feedback that is still relevant to the post is not lost.